# SQL request on a newly saved Grails object

Tags: sql, grails, h2

I don't understand why my request returns me an empty array with the code below.

Using grails and an H2 database

```
Animal lion = new Animal()
lion.save()

println lion.id
println sql.rows("select * from animal")
```

The outputs are

```
1
[]
```

Why do I get an empty array ?

If I go and check in the memory database at

```
localhost/Zoo/dbconsole
```

I get the line as I should be having. Is there some kind of a time limit that I have to wait before doing my sql request ?

Comment: I assume this is Grails, so I changed the tags/title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this in Grails?  If so, try:

```
lion.save( flush: true )
```

It's probably that Hibernate hasn't flushed the changes to the database before you do your select (especially as it looks like the above code is all in the same transaction).

Comment: Yes, yes it's all in the same transaction. I went and checked the grails documentation and still not working (surprises me btw) Have any other idea how I could do this ?

Comment: Did you add `flush: true`?

Comment: Yes, yes, I did. I modified a little my datasource, putting my db to a file instead of in memory and used GORM and it's working. Don't know which one of them made it work, but at least it's working fine now :) You're `flush: true` helped as well